# Cannot save an image file locally, what is the best way to save an image file besides base64 string and fetch it from an API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js

I'm using NextJS in my application, and I take an Image as an input from the user. ( `input type="file"` ). Since I can't save files locally in NextJS, I have to keep these images as base64 string somewhere else.

I'm using mongodb as my database, I send a request to my mongodb server, it keeps this base64 string, then in another page in my project, I GET request to mongodb server, get this base64 string, and showing it on the page.

However, even if there are 5-6 images (as base64 string), the webpage stops working beacuse it reaches more than 10 MB, **keeping the image as base64 string takes too much space**.

So, I can't save the image locally, I can't keep it as base64 string because even with 4-5 images it takes around 20MB storage (I'm expecting   hundreds and thousands images) and this is not  sustainable.

What's the correct way to save an image in this situation? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Databases can handle binary data quite fine, so why _store_ base64 in the first place? But base64 only increases the data to 4/3 of its original size, so even if you stored the binary data only, you'd probably run into problems quite quick. _"What's the correct way to save an image in this situation?"_ - for starters: The file system, instead of a database. (And if your current stack does not allow you to store them in a file system - then you will probably have to overthink your stack.)

Comment: Dont use Database for image storage, store image on any server and store url into your databse.